# why `./file.py` was working but `bash file.py` not work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, python

Why `./file.py` was working, but `bash file.py` not work?
When i run `bash file.py` or `. file.py` or `source file.py` get error like this:
`file.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected .....`
But `./file.py` works fine.

`file.py`
`#!/usr/bin/python3.4
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("something")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When starting a script (as a command), it looks at the hash-bang (`#!`) to know what to use to start the script. In your script, I'm betting it starts with `#!/usr/bin/python` or similar. When you start it as `./script.py`, it reads that first line and executes `/usr/bin/python ./script.py` secretly.

If you prepend it by using `bash ./script.py`, it expects the interpreter to be Bash, not Python.

Comment: More precisely, if you use `bash ./script.py`, it *tries to interpret it as a bash script* instead of python. It's *not* a bash script, so the syntax is all wrong, and it errors out.